# SQL Server Dynamic Pivot: remove fully NULL columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2014. I am working a stored procedure that returns a table.

We have two input parameters, @from and @until, which define start and end of date ranges we will be searching by.

At the end of our query, we use PIVOT to turn columns into rows.

I am able to SELECT the data correctly, but have one problem after the PIVOT: 
many of the columns come back fully NULL, because they were not included in the date range set by @from and @until.

What can I do so that I don't get those `NULL` columns at all?

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[presupuestosVenta] 
    @from char(8), (in this case 201501)
    @until char(8) (in this case 201506)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @venta TABLE
(
    LAPSO_DOC CHAR(6),
    ID_EXT_ITM CHAR(3),
    ID_TALLA CHAR(6),
    VENTA INT
)

INSERT INTO @venta 
SELECT
    LAPSO_DOC,
    ID_EXT_ITM,
    ID_TALLA,
    CAST (CANTIDAD_CAP AS INT) AS VENTA
FROM dbo.a_presupuestosVenta
WHERE 
(   ID_REFER = '312177000' 
    OR ID_REFER = '314001000' 
    OR ID_REFER = '315099000'
) 
AND LAPSO_DOC BETWEEN @from AND @until  

SELECT *
FROM @venta
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(VENTA) 
    FOR LAPSO_DOC
    IN ([201501],[201502], [201503], [201504],[201505], [201506] )
) 
AS PivotTable   
ORDER BY ID_EXT_ITM DESC, ID_TALLA ASC
END
```

Here are the results I am getting:

[image: sql results]

EDIT: I've been working on a DYNAMIC PIVOT QUERY, but keep getting an error saying my table @venta is not defined:

```
    DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @columns = N'';

    SELECT @columns += N', v.' + QUOTENAME(LAPSO_DOC)
    FROM (SELECT v.LAPSO_DOC FROM @venta AS v
    GROUP BY v.LAPSO_DOC) AS x;
    SET @sql = N'
    SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
    FROM
    (
        SELECT v.VENTA, v.LAPSO_DOC
        FROM @venta as v
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(VENTA) FOR LAPSO_DOC IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', v.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS v;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Is this the actual code?  If so, how did you determine the IN clause in your pivot statement?  The procedure shows `@from` AND `@until` passed in as parameters, but your IN clause hard coded.  It certainly looks like you need to build dynamic sql to generate the IN clause.  In which case you can just select the unique LAPSO_DOC values when building the sql.  Joe's answer below has a link to more details on building a dynamic pivot.

Comment: Yes, they are currently hardcoded. Yes, I think you are right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to build this as a dynamic query.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/